# Is there a version/equivalent of SleepConditionVariableCS() which uses a non-recursive mutex (like) object?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, thread-safety

I am writing the Windows port for a Linux application and I am trying to find a suitable replacement for `pthread_cond_wait()`. The closest alternative seems to be `SleepConditionVariableCS()`. However I am unwilling to use this function because it uses *CriticalSections* which are basically lightweight recursive mutexes. I would prefer a non-recursive lock object alternative - is there one?

P.S. -

1. In the application in place of pthread mutexes I am using [Semaphores](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682438(v=vs.85).aspx) with maximum count 1.
2. If recursive mutexes are as problematic [as stated by David Butenhof](http://www.zaval.org/resources/library/butenhof1.html) then why does Windows provide only recursive Mutexes (or CriticalSection) as an option? Is this a massive #Fail on part of Windows or is David Butenhof outdated/wrong?

Comment: The concurrency runtime also provides condition variables but you won't like those either.  Recursive locks are just a feature of a company with a 1-800 support phone number and an operating system that makes them *very* cheap to create.  If you are trying to do this because you assume it will be cheaper then don't bother.  Consider [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref) to make you feel better about it.

Comment: FWIW, you can easily convert a recursive mutex into a non-recursive one.  Just increment a counter when you claim the mutex, verify that it is equal to one, and decrement it when you release it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Vista and later provide [Slim Reader/Writer (SRW) Locks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904937(VS.85).aspx) as a non-recursive lock object alternative <sup>1</sup>.

As the documentation states:

> An SRW lock is the size of a pointer. The advantage is that it is fast to update the lock state. The disadvantage is that very little state information can be stored, so **SRW locks cannot be acquired recursively**. In addition, a thread that owns an SRW lock in shared mode cannot upgrade its ownership of the lock to exclusive mode.

A Windows Condition Variable can use a SRW lock instead of a CriticalSection lock. See [`SleepConditionVariableSRW()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686304.aspx).

<sup>1</sup>: PS. Here's another view on the good vs. bad of [recursive locks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/recursive-re-entrant-locks.html) .

Comment: Windows' Condition Variables can use SRW locks instead of CriticalSection locks. See [`SleepConditionVariableSRW()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686304.aspx).

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Could you post that as a separate answer. This is exactly what I was looking for.